# Equivalent expressions for "Note that"

Tags: phrase-request, synonyms

What are some equivalent expressions for "Note that" ?

Note that I am using "Note that" at the beginning of a sentence to make a remark..

Comment: You can use the abbreviation **n.b.** which stands for the latin **nota bene**- note well.

Comment: Can you please give us come context? How are you trying to use this? This will help us target more accurately what you're looking for and prevent poor suggestions that don't actually fit. If you have an example sentence, that would help a lot!

Comment: @Catija in my case, I am using "Note that" at the beginning of a sentence to make a sort of remark...

Comment: Your question is in danger of being closed. Adding an example sentence will make this much easier for us to answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

'n.b.' (an abbreviation for the Latin "nota bene" or "note well [that]") can be used at the start of a sentence.

"Note that..." is a perfectly acceptable start to a sentence, as can "Please note..."

"Take care to..." or "Take care to ensure that you..." are also used.